# Duplicate fields in col query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with books, authors and genres

I want to get output result as: book, author and genres, but when I do this query, I have duplicate fields, if books have 5 genres in example first row of query result) author row duplicates 5 too or reverse.

Example on SQL Fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a15d8/1

I need to in first row:

book | one author | five genres
...
etc.

Comment: MySQL DISTINCT operator with the SELECT statement to eliminate duplicate rows in the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, add DISTINCT to line 4, and you won't have any duplicates. However, you may still return more than one author (unique), but that's what your query should return the way it is.

like:

```
group_concat(DISTINCT concat_ws (' ',`a`.`last_name`,`a`.`first_name`,`a`.`middle_name`)) as author,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your schema. Just some thoughts to share:
(I know this does not answer your question but trust me: using a good schema from the beginning can save you a lot of work later)

1. In your books table use the `author.id` as foreign key. Otherwise you will have trouble as soon as you get duplicate names (which is possible). Joining those tables will also become ways easier.
2. You will most likely have a certain set of genres and will assign them to your books. This is a n:m-relationship. Meaning one book can have multiple genres and one genre can be assigned to multiple books. You will need a relationship table to do this. The Relationship table will then contain the ID of a book and the ID of a genre and link them.